# Installable onEdit trigger firing twice Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

My question is simple. If I have a function named 'onEdit' in a Google Apps Script that I have set up as an installable trigger, will it fire twice? As in once for simple trigger behaviour and once for installable trigger behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a simple trigger and an installable trigger setup for that onEdit then yes you will  get two trigger events.

Comment: Your answer is correct but incomplete. It will fire twice only if the function doesn't include any call to a service requiring authorization. Otherwise only the installable trigger would work. Anyway, the best thing to do is to use different names for the installable one to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Just as a follow up to this. There arises an issue if you set up an installable and simple trigger for the same event and then access a library. During this, permissions don't seem to transfer correctly to the library causing script failure.

Comment: @Sergeinsas I actually have a case in which I have a service requiring authorization and it fires both triggers. I asked a question about this case here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65799452/google-script-has-two-triggers-for-on-edit-can-i-remove-the-simple-one

Comment: @Sergeinsas Pretty much all of my answers are incomplete because I'm only interested in answering the question that I'm asked.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question has been answered but what worked for me was not naming my method "onEdit" because it will automatically run when editing any cell of the sheet. You just have to install onEdit as a trigger if it requires something with another authorization scope.

Comment: Yes if you have installed an onEdit trigger then you don't want to name your function onEdit() because it will fire twice.  One for the simple trigger and one for the installable trigger.