# Google Sheets OnEdit() - You do not have permission to call a service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

```
function onEdit(e){                  
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile( 'MyHtmlFile' )
          .evaluate()
          .setWidth( 800 )
          .setHeight( 400 );  
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
          .showModalDialog( html, 'My page title' ); 
}
```

When I edit a Spreadsheet's cell **NO pop up is shown** but I got this **error in the console**:

> Google Apps Script: You do not have permission to call showModalDialog

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask for user input in "on edit" installable trigger in Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479954/how-to-ask-for-user-input-in-on-edit-installable-trigger-in-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `onEdit()` will have to be an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) because it is using a service that requires authorization.

**note:** rename `onEdit()` when using it as an installable trigger to avoid [possible issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46248933/8272952)

> Like simple triggers, installable triggers let Apps Script run a function automatically when a certain event, such as opening a document, occurs. **Installable triggers, however, offer more flexibility than simple triggers: they can call services that require authorization**, ...

[Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually):

To manually create an installable trigger through a dialog in the script editor, follow these steps:

1. From the script editor, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.
2. Click the link that says: No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
3. Under Run, select the name of function you want to trigger.
4. Under Events, select either Time-driven or the Google App that the script is bound to (for example, From spreadsheet).
5. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create (for example, an Hour timer that runs Every hour or an On open trigger).
6. Optionally, click Notifications to configure how and when you will be contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
7. Click Save.

Comment: Be aware that Google recently changed behaviour of installable triggers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479954/how-to-ask-for-user-input-in-on-edit-installable-trigger-in-google-spreadsheet/

Comment: As long as @MisaelSab is the one to install the trigger, it is a working solution to the problem code above, hence the [Managing triggers manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). If they can access the code they should be able to set an installable trigger, correcting the error. On a different note, that change is good to know and may be the cause of an error I have been seeing in one of my projects, thank you for that

Comment: If it is a simple trigger, the error does happen. The code above was tested on a new sheet and the error was reproduced. Once it was moved to an installable trigger, it worked correctly

Comment: I guess you are right, the breaking change Google made is that `showModalDialog` now requires user authorization, so it no longer can be used in simple triggers

Comment: Using onEdit which is a reserved function name for an installable triggers could cause unexpected results. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46248743/1595451

Comment: @Rubén Thank you, I see where my wording would cause confusion, added a note for clarity

Comment: The use of installable triggers is also the way to go for failures for insufficient permissions on UrlFetchApp.fetch calls from triggered events.

Answer (score 2):

This answer serves documentation purposes.

- You can also create the installable `onEdit` trigger via a script if you want to avoid the manual work of installing the trigger.

In order to create an **installable** `onEdit` trigger for `myFunction`, execute **only** and **once** the `create_onEdit` function below:

```
function myFunction(){    
     var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile( 'MyHtmlFile' )
              .evaluate()
              .setWidth( 800 )
              .setHeight( 400 );
              SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
              .showModalDialog( html, 'My page title' ); 
}

function create_onEdit(){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
    .onEdit()
    .create(); 
}
```

**References:**

- [Class TriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forspreadsheetsheet)