# part of the event function code does not work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code in a script:

```
if(descrid == 'A') {
  if(sheet.getRange('C42').isBlank())
  {var input = Browser.inputBox("POR FAVOR, INGRESA OBSERVACION " +descrid)
   sheet.getRange('C42').setValue('Obs "A" (HORA: ' + hora + ') - ' + input)
 }
   else { Browser.msgBox('OBSERVACION "A" YA EXISTE')
   } 
  }
```

An installable trigger is assigned for this function. Problem is that for the sheet owner it works perfectly, but for any shared user - 'else' condition works - message box appears but inputBox never shows up.

UPD: I found out that msgBox works perfectly for everybody but inputBox does not work neither with simple nor with installable trigger for user. Same for ui.prompt
simple functions

```
function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()

var response = ui.prompt('May I know your name?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO)}
//Browser.inputBox('test')}
```

does not work for user either trigger is simple or installed. But works for the owner.

UPD2: script works for user if it is assigned for button. but onEdit - still only for the owner.
What can be a problem?

Comment: but ELSE part of the code works - if C42 is NOT blank, user gets messageBox.

Comment: Possibly related to other parts of the function (show your code), or unexpected behavior from `Browser`, which is not recommended. Same issues with the recommended [`Ui`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs) [methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui)?

Comment: I edited my primary post - problem is in some simple things. please check

Comment: Do the other users have [edit permissions for the sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound)? Have users [authorized the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50263317/google-app-script-you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-prompt)?

Comment: sure. moreover, there are several other triggered scripts and they work perfectly for users. only inputBox does not work based on onEdit. That is all

Comment: By 'assigned for button', you mean via the menu UI? Then yes, [have the user authorize the script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479954/how-to-ask-for-user-input-in-on-edit-installable-trigger-in-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ask for user input in "on edit" installable trigger in Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479954/how-to-ask-for-user-input-in-on-edit-installable-trigger-in-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: by assigned to a button I mean assign script to a picture. I passed through the recommendations following the link but it didn't help. As I mentioned - there are many other triggered onEdit scripts that work well for users. only inputBox and ui.prompt show up only for the owner. I also tried other web-browsers.