# Script fails on SpreadsheetApp.openById - Requires permission

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, google-api, triggers

I have an onOpen function that creates a custom menu in a spreadsheet.  It's been working fine for over a year, but a couple days ago it stopped working.

When I look at the execution transcript I get:

"Execution failed: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"

This fails/relates to the below line of code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myID")
```

I've checked what API's are enabled, and I have Sheets enabled, which is reflected in the .json file.  I don't have @OnlyCurrentDoc anywhere in the script.  I've reset the permissions on the account for this script, ran the function again and allowed permissions, but still the menu will not create on open.

My .json file:

```
{
"timeZone": "Europe/London",
"dependencies": {
"enabledAdvancedServices": [{
  "userSymbol": "Sheets",
  "serviceId": "sheets",
  "version": "v4"
 }]
},
"exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Sheets OnEdit() - You do not have permission to call showModalDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675320/google-sheets-onedit-you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-showmodaldialog)

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs because the code doesn't have enough permissions to run that method. The `openById` method requires one or more of [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#authorization_12) scopes. Your manifest .JSON should look like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/London",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [{
      "userSymbol": "Sheets",
      "serviceId": "sheets",
      "version": "v4"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]
}
```

Notice how I added the scope at the end of the file. Please, don't hesitate to ask for more clarification to this answer.

Comment: Scope detection and addition will happen automatically. OP's problem  probably is usage of simple `onOpen()` trigger, which doesn't  have permission to open other spreadsheets.

Comment: @TheMaster How can I give the trigger permission?

Jacques-Guzel Heron - I did try adding that to my json before but it made no difference, so I took it back out.  When I run the function manually, it works fine.

Comment: @Aidan Look into the duplicate  question above. You need "installable triggers". Read managing triggers manually

Comment: @Aidan From the documentation of [installable triggers][1] I read "*An installable open trigger runs when a user opens a spreadsheet […] that they have permission to edit*". So just to make sure that I am not missing something, can you confirm that you are the owner of that file?


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Yes I'm the owner of the doc.

Comment: @TheMaster - I've already manually set an installable trigger to run onOpen, this is how it was working previously.

Comment: @Aidan remove trigger> rename onOpen() to installableOpen() > create trigger for the new function on open manually in https://script.google.com/home/triggers .

Comment: Hi @Aidan, please test the previous comment of TheMaster and if it doesn't work out, could you please tell us how are you calculating the ID of the sheet? I want to know if it is hardcoded or it comes from a different method.