# Calling function doImport from function onOpen works, but from onEdit does not. Why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This works fine as is exectued as intended everytime the spreadsheet is opened:

```
function onOpen() {
  doImport();
};

function doImport() {
//Destination
  var destinationSpreadsheet = ...
```

But this does not:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'E8') {
    if (/^\w+$/.test(e.value)) {        
      eval(e.value)();
      e.range.clear({contentsOnly: true});
    };
  };
};

function Now() {
Logger.log("in function Now "); 
  doImport();
Logger.log("in function Now after call to doImport");   
};
```

The statement `Logger.log("in function Now ");` is called, but the statement `Logger.log("in function Now after call to doImport");` is not called.

I supposed that it could have to do with triggers and tried around but with no luck.

Any suggestions out there?

Comment: Read all the restrictions listed on: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Comment: As you have mentioned, function "doImport" is working in onOpen, so can you show us the code of doImport

Comment: I don't see how you're calling `doImport` from the `onEdit`. Could you please share the spreadsheet you're working on, as well as `doImport`?

Comment: Solved by following this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58025650/script-fails-on-spreadsheetapp-openbyid-requires-permission

Comment: Solved by following this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58025650/script-fails-on-spreadsheetapp-openbyid-requires-permission