# onEdit runs only half of the script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I need to use a script that sends data from one sheet to a different one and to clear the values after writing on a specific cell.

I've tried onEdit and it clears the values but doesn't insert them in the second sheet. This is the code I have so far:

```
function onEdit(e) {

if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "F6"){

//Copiar los datos originales 
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Hoja 1"); 
var A = sheet1.getRange("B5").getValues();
var B = sheet1.getRange("F5").getValues();
var C = sheet1.getRange("A8:F22").getValues();

//Borrar valores de la hoja de origen después de copiar

var borrar = sheet1.getRange("B5").clearContent();
var borrar = sheet1.getRange("F6").clearContent();
var borrar = sheet1.getRange("A8:F22").clearContent();

//Spreadsheet en la que voy a copiar lo anterior 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zF84h_gR0zHPqwobYyuOQlo50L2ktpZr2e4orMNtqE8/edit#gid=382646794'); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PEDIDOS SIN ORDENAR"); 
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; 

//Insertar los valores 
var destRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, A.length, A[0].length).setValues(A);
var destRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2, B.length, B[0].length).setValues(B);
var destRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3, C.length, C[0].length).setValues(C);


}}
```

If I change the name of the code and don't condition it to the content of cell F6, then the code runs completely. For that reason I tried to use a button, which works perfetly fine in PC but I need it to work also in mobile devices and buttons don't work with Android.

My last try was:

```
function Enviar() {

//if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "F6"){

//Copiar los datos originales 
var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName("Hoja 1"); 
var A = sheet1.getRange("B5").getValues();
var B = sheet1.getRange("F5").getValues();
var C = sheet1.getRange("A8:F22").getValues();

//Borrar valores de la hoja de origen después de copiar

var borrar = sheet1.getRange("B5").clearContent();
var borrar = sheet1.getRange("F6").clearContent();
var borrar = sheet1.getRange("A8:F22").clearContent();

var D = sheet1.getRange("F6").getValues()
if (D == "SI"){
//Spreadsheet en la que voy a copiar lo anterior 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zF84h_gR0zHPqwobYyuOQlo50L2ktpZr2e4orMNtqE8/edit#gid=382646794'); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PEDIDOS SIN ORDENAR"); 
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1; 

//Insertar los valores 
var destRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, A.length, A[0].length).setValues(A);
var destRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2, B.length, B[0].length).setValues(B);
var destRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3, C.length, C[0].length).setValues(C);


}}
```

This last try doesn't seem to do anything at all.
None of my tries shows error, the script runs but doesn't give the expected results.

I don't know what else I could do. Please I need some help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets OnEdit() - You do not have permission to call showModalDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675320/google-sheets-onedit-you-do-not-have-permission-to-call-showmodaldialog)

Comment: You need to learn to debug. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for "troubleshooting".

Comment: You're right, it shows an error but after looking for info, I still don't know how to solve it: Exception: You don't have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl. Necessary permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
    at onEdit(Código:21:25)

Comment: Read the answer in my first comment

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I don't understand completely because I'm new at this. I had already read it but I think the answer explains how to create an installable trigger, which isn't what I need because it would affect edditing anywhere in the spreadsheet and I need it to run only after a specific cell is edited (F6). Besides I am the owner of both spreadsheets and the script, so I don't understand why that error takes place. I changed the name of the function but left everything else the same as someone suggested & now error is: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (línea 3, archivo "Código")

Comment: Now it works, not sure how I did it but it's working propperly now. Thanks you very much for your help and patience

Comment: Installable trigger is what you need. Simple triggers run anonymously.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Enviar(e) {
  //Currently this function runs for any edit of any sheet you should consider limiting it to only the sheet and cell range that you desire
  var ss1=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sh1=e.source.getSheetByName("Hoja 1"); 
  var A=sh1.getRange("B5").getValue();//single value
  var B=sh1.getRange("F5").getValue();//single value
  var C=sh1.getRange("A8:F22").getValues();//2D array
  var borrar=sh1.getRange("B5").clearContent();
  var borrar=sh1.getRange("F6").clearContent();
  var borrar=sh1.getRange("A8:F22").clearContent();
  var D=sh1.getRange("F6").getValue()
  if (D=="SI"){
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zF84h_gR0zHPqwobYyuOQlo50L2ktpZr2e4orMNtqE8/edit#gid=382646794'); 
    var sh=ss.getSheetByName("PEDIDOS SIN ORDENAR"); 
    var lastRow=sh.getLastRow() + 1; 
    var destRange=sh.getRange(lastRow,1).setValue(A);//single value
    var destRange=sh.getRange(lastRow,2).setValue(B);//single value
    var destRange=sh.getRange(lastRow, 3,C.length,C[0].length).setValues(C);//2D array    
  }
}
```