# When Certain cells are edited, run script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how I can get my script to run when cells `C3` or `E3` are edited.

The cells in question have a drop down data validation list, and is shared with numerous people who will be adjusting those values.
I want to reset these values 5 minutes after those cells were last changed.

I have a script that will change them with a 5 minute delay, but it works if any cell in the spreadsheet is amended but I would only like it run once those specific cells are edited.

This is what I have so far.

```
function OnEdit(e) {
  Utilities.sleep(300000);// pause in the loop for 300000 milliseconds
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var RD = ss.getRange("C3").setValue("ALL")
  var Branch = ss.getRange("E3").setValue("ALL")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

To make sure we are on the same page.

- According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), simple `onEdit` triggers cannot run for longer than 30 seconds. In your case you want to run the script for more than 300 seconds
- Therefore, it makes sense to use an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) `onEdit` trigger which is subject to the [quota limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).
- Take advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) to minimize unecessary calls.
- Last but not least, your current solution is being executed for 300 seconds regardless of the cell that was edited. You want to wait for 300 seconds only if `C3` or `E3` is edited. [Includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) can be used for that purpose.

### Solution:

Please follow the next two steps:

1. Change the name of your function from `OnEdit(e)` to something else e.g. `myFunction(e)` and create an **installable** trigger for that function via the project's trigger menu or [programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666338/11225291).
2. Adjust your script to the following solution:

   ```
   function myFunction(e) {
      const ar = e.range;
      const as = ar.getSheet();
      const cells = ["C3","E3"]; // add cells you want to be edited to activate the script
      // if C3 or E3 is edited, wait for 300 seconds
      if (as.getName()=="Sheet1" && cells.includes(ar.getA1Notation())){
           Utilities.sleep(300000);
           as.getRange("C3").setValue("ALL");
           as.getRange("E3").setValue("ALL");
      }
   }
   ```