# Google Script has two triggers for on edit. Can I remove the "simple" one?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Spreadsheet script with an onEdit trigger. For some reason two `onEdit` triggers are "fired": an installed trigger and a simple trigger. I set up `onEdit` to send an email. This was authenticated for the installed trigger and works fine. However, each time it fires the simple trigger it throws an exception. Is it possible to remove or disable the simple trigger so that it doesn't throw the exception?

[image]

I wrote a simple function to check what triggers my script was using. It only shows one `onEdit` trigger, even though it triggers both simple and installed.

```
function checkTriggers(){
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  triggers.forEach(function(trigger){console.log(trigger.getHandlerFunction())});
}
```

Screenshot of `checkTriggers()` output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Merge both `onEdit` triggers:

Assuming you have 2 `onEdit` triggers. One simple which is called `onEdit(e)` and one installable which is called `myFunction(e)`. Since you have already authorized `myFunction(e)` and it is an installable trigger, you can rename your `onEdit(e)` simple trigger to a different name e.g. `myFunction2(e)` and put inside `myFunction(e)`:

```
function myFunction(e){
  //code for the installable myFunction
  myFunction2(e) 
}
```

In this way both `myFunction` and `myFunction2` will be triggered. If you want to remove `myFunction2` altogether, then simply remove or comment out the code that relates to that.

### Issue with the simple `onEdit(e)` trigger:

Remove the simple `onEdit(e)` trigger as it can't be used in your case because your script uses services that require authorization.

- Change the name of the function from `onEdit(e)` to something else e.g. `myFunction(e)`.
- Create an **installable** `onEdit` trigger for `myFunction`.
- To create an installable trigger for `myFunction` use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65666338/11225291). Namely, execute the `create_onEdit` function:

  ```
  function create_onEdit(){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
    .onEdit()
    .create(); 
  }
  ```

and make sure `myFunction(e)` lives in the same script editor.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify, I had one onEdit function. I renamed it to onCellEdit, deleted the onEdit trigger, and then recreated the trigger in the Triggers tab. This works fine and I only have one trigger fired. The key takeaway that I was unaware of is that using default naming creates a simple trigger.

Comment: @galactikuh exactly :) Using `onEdit` as a function name a simple `onEdit` trigger is created automatically. Installable triggers needs to be set up by you (either via script) or manually from the trigger creation menu.